# django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet django 1.9

Tags: django, python-3.x

Im using Django 1.9 on windows 7.

When I execute 
'python manage.py runserver'
I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
350, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
342, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
176, in fetch_command
    commands = get_commands()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\functools.py", line 448, in wrapper
    result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
71, in get_commands
    for app_config in reversed(list(apps.get_app_configs())):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 137, in get
_app_configs
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 124, in che
ck_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Happened to me also, but I was migrating from previous django version, check your settings because something has changed, if this is the case

Comment: In my  case I have installed django 1.9 itself and have not migrated. Im stuck with this error.